# Can you pass a WebGrid item when calling window.Open

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a button in one of my WebGrid columns. If the button is clicked, I am popping up a window using the following code:

```
window.open('/Home/Message', '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, scrollbar=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400');
```

"Message" is another view that I have created that fills the popup window. I need to be able to pass the row object into that window for that particular button press. I assume there is a way to do that.

This is my Message ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Message()
    {
        var model = new MessageViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

But I really want to have a parameter on that method for the row object.

EDIT: More details.

So I have a button in my webgrid column like so:

```
grid.Column(header: "Fault", format: (item) =>
            {
                if (item.Fault != null)
                {
                    return new HtmlString("<input type='submit' id='btnShowFault' value='Fault' />");
                }

                return "";
            }))
```

And here is the javascript to that is called when it is clicked:

```
 $(function () {
    $("#btnShowFault").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        window.open('/Home/Message', '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, scrollbar=yes, resizable=yes, menubar=no, top=200, left=500, width=400, height=250');
    });
});
```

So I guess what I really needs is two fold.

1. How to get the row item from the grid into that function.
2. How to pass that into the window.open call.

I assume this is possible as this is really easy to do in things like wpf and silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching window.open and did a dialog instead. It was just too difficult to work with to have anything beyond just text.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this

`window.open('/Home/Message?field1=value1&field2=value2...', '_blank',` `'toolbar=yes, scrollbar=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400,` `height=400');`

Where

`class MessageViewModel()`

`{`

 `public string fireld1{get; set;}`

`public string fireld2{get; set;}`

`...............................`

`}`

Comment: I edited my question with some more details. Take a look and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: You can get row item from Model by clicked row id, or from DOM

Comment: return new HtmlString("<input type='submit' onclick=' SameFunction(item) ' id='btnShowFault' value='Fault' />");
 function SameFunction(item){...}

Comment: It gives an error Uncaught Reference Error: item is not defined.

Comment: No. The model on the view contains a list that gets bound to the WebGrid.

Comment: My example:
@model List<DishModel>
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10, grid.Column("", header: "Actions", format: @<text> <button id="edit" onclick="editDish(this);" style="font-size:8pt; width:55px; background-color:#E6FFFF; border-radius:7px" >Edit</button></text>)
function editDish(obj) {var td = $(obj).closest('tr').find('td');
        $('#DishID').val($(td[0]).text());
        $('#Name').val($(td[1]).text());
        $('#Description').val($(td[2]).text());
...}

Comment: Can you edit and paste all that into your answer so that it is formatted properly, please?

Comment: Html header:
@model List<DishModel>
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
}

Comment: HTML:
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: new[] {

        grid.Column("DishID", "DishID"),
        grid.Column("Name", "Name"),
        grid.Column("Description","Description", style: "description"),
        grid.Column("", header: "Actions", format: @<text>
                                                        <button id="edit" onclick="editDish(this);" style="font-size:8pt; width:55px; background-color:#E6FFFF; " >Edit</button>
</text>)
})

Comment: Javascript:
function editDish(obj) {
        var td = $(obj).closest('tr').find('td');
        $('#DishID').val($(td[0]).text());
        $('#Name').val($(td[1]).text());
        $('#Description').val($(td[2]).text());

       var id = $(td[0]).text();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetProduct", "Home")',
            type: 'Post',
            data: { productID: id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            ...
            }
        });

Comment: I can't make my model the binding list of the webgrid. I need other things in this view besides just that binding list.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/875859/Insert-Update-and-Delete-MVC-WebGrid-Data-using-JQ